# How to create a NSTimer in Iphonesdk

Tags: iphone, ipad

I am new to Iphone programming I want to know about how to create a NSTimer in Xcode Iphonesdk. Can anyone suggest me?

Comment: What do you want it for?

Answer (score 3):

`NSTimer *timer = [NSTimer scheduleTimerWithTimeInterval:TIME_INTERVAL target:self selector:@selector(YOUR_METHOD_NAME) userInfo:nil repeats:YES/NO];`

Hope this will help you........

Answer (score 0):

**Here is a code to add NSTimer..**

```
1) in .h file
NSTimer *timer;

2) in .m file
timer = [NSTimer scheduledTimerWithTimeInterval:1.0 target:self selector:@selector(YOUR_METHOD_NAME) userInfo:nil repeats:YES];
```

**Note:: so your method will continuously call after every 1 second.. and if you want to call the timer method only once set repeats:NO...**

**To Invalidate Timer**

```
3) to invalidate the timer where you want..
   [timer invalidate];
```